# for loop show last image. i want image one by one on canvas... on same x and y axis

Tags: android

```
public class MyBringBackSurface extends SurfaceView implements Runnable 
    {
        SurfaceHolder ourHolder;
        Thread ourThread;
        boolean isRunning=false;
        Bitmap[] bitmap={BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.dice1),
                BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.dice2),
                BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.dice3)

        };

        public MyBringBackSurface(Context context) {
            super(context);
            ourHolder=getHolder();

        }
        @Override
        public void run() 
        {

            while(isRunning)
            {
                if(!ourHolder.getSurface().isValid())
                    continue;
                Canvas canvas = ourHolder.lockCanvas();
                Bitmap[] bitmap={BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.dice1),
                        BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.dice2),
                        BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.dice3)};
                for(timer=0; timer< bitmap.length; timer++)
                {
                    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap[timer], 10,20,null);
                }
                ourHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
            }   
        }
        public void pause() {
            isRunning = false;
            while(true)
            {
                try 
                {
                    ourThread.join();
                } 
                catch (InterruptedException e) 
                {   
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                break;
            }
            ourThread=null;
        }
        public void resume()
        {
            isRunning = true;
            ourThread= new Thread(this);
            ourThread.start();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: you are drawing the image on the same co-ordinates. thats why you see the last draw canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap[timer], 10,20,null);

Comment: Please add a question to the body of the text. Is what you want is each `bitmap[]` entry to be sequentially drawn to simulate a die roll?

Comment: @Raghunandan: yes i know that i am drawing on the same co-ordinate.. but actually that is my requirement. Actually I hav 23 image of a dice. and i want to draw them like that looks like a dice is rolling.

Answer (score 0):

put

```
  try{
  Thread.sleep(1000);    
  canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap[timer], 10,20,null);
  }catch(InterruptedException e){
}
```

does it meets your answer ?